# Spectra of the energy flux VS transfer spectra?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, simulation, data-analysis

In direct numerical simulation of turbulence what is the advantage to look at the spectra of the energy flux rather than the transfer spectra?

The transfer spectra corresponds to the triple-velocity correlation coming from the non-linear interaction of the Navier-Stokes equations.
The transfer spectra is generally noted:
\begin{equation}
T(\mathbf{k},t)
\end{equation}
The energy flux through wave number $\mathbf{k}$ is defined from the transfer spectra by
\begin{equation}
\Pi(\mathbf{k},t)=\int^{\infty}_{\mathbf{k}}T(\mathbf{p},t)d\mathbf{p}=-\int^{\mathbf{k}}_{0}T(\mathbf{p},t)d\mathbf{p}
\end{equation}